# java stacks and an apparent pointless exercise

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to verify my understanding of stacks.  While I'm starting to understand the basics and I still have a ways to go, I found an example that piqued my curiosity.

My research included this thread:

[Understanding Postfix-expression Evaluation in Java code using a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542610/understanding-postfix-expression-evaluation-in-java-code-using-a-stack)

I am confused by one line in particular from the thread I referenced above.

Here is the entire section of code - my question refers to the line inside the while loop - details after the code:

```
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    char[] a = args[0].toCharArray();
    int N =a.length;
    intStack s = new intStack();
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]=='+')
        {
            s.push(s.pop() + s.pop());
        }
        if (a[i]=='*')
        {
            s.push(s.pop() * s.pop());
        }
        if ((a[i] >= '0') && (a[i] <= '9'))
        {
            s.push(0);
        }
        while ((a[i] >= '0') && (a[i] <= '9'))
        {
            s.push(10*s.pop() + (a[i++]-'0'));
        }
        Out.println(s.pop() + "");
    }
    }
```

My question is this: what purpose does the `-'0'` serve?  If I understand the rest of the line properly, we are referencing the char 0 (due to the single quotes) and the `-` appears to be the operator for subtraction.  Subtracting zero - a hard-coded zero, as opposed to a variable that just might happen to be zero occasionally - seems pointless.

My current assumption is that there is a finely nuanced answer to this - i.e. it only /appears/ to be a pointless exercise, but there is something truly magical happening that I am simply too dim to understand.

Thanks in advance to everyone here - I've been learning a great deal from the advice - this has quickly become one of my favorite and most-visited sites.

Best regards

Comment: Many thanks for the replies - makes perfect sense now.  Very similar to what I have done previously in Excel - multiplying digits formatted as text (a string) by 1 to convert the cell to a number.

Is something similar happening in the last line? `+ "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `a` is an array of `char` that holds numerical digits, `a[i++]-'0'` is a quick way of getting the numerical value of the `char` at `a[i++]`. Think of it as subtracting the ASCII code for `0` from the ASCII code for whatever is in that position of the character array.

Answer (score 2):

Characters are represented using some encoding. In ASCII, the character `0` is represented by 48, `1` is 49, etc. So if the encoded character is between `[48,57]` then subtracting `'0'` (value of 48) you get the integer value of the character.

Answer (score 0):

The `-'0'` is just a shorthand method of conversion between `ascii` and `ints`. Your stack is storing single digit numbers as `chars`, see the 2nd conversion below.

[image]

Conversion from 1-digit `int` to numeric `char`

```
int x = 1;
char c = x + '0';
```

Conversion from numeric `char` to int

```
char c = '5';
int x = c - '0';
```

Conversion from `int` to lowercase alphabetic `char` (0='a', 25='z')

```
int x = 1;
char c = x + 'a';
```

Conversion from lowercase alphabetic `char` to int

```
char c = 'm';
int x = c - 'a';
```

Conversion from `int` to uppercase alphabetic `char` (0='A', 25='Z')

```
int x = 1;
char c = x + 'A';
```

Conversion from uppercase alphabetic `char` to int

```
char c = 'M'; // 'M'=77
int x = c - 'A'; // 77-65=12 therefore 'M is element 12 of the alphabet (A=0)
```

These work because:

```
0+48 = 0+'0' = '0'
0+65 = 0+'A' = 'A'
0+97 = 0+'a' = 'a'
```

Comment: Hi, Ron - tons of great info here, many thanks.  I'm trying to wrap my head around implementing the conversions in an actual scenario.  Adding or subtracting the values depends on the type you start with and to what you wish to convert.  That makes sense.

In your examples, you assign 0 to 'a' and 'A' - I'm assuming this is simply to indicate that it is the first letter - I was momentarily confused when I expected to see a value from the table above instead (97 or 65).

So, if x=1 and we add 'a', does that return 'b'?

Comment: @Mac Yes! 1+'a' = 'b' Perhaps you should review that `char` is a numerical type, `'a'` is the exact same as `97` and `0x61`.